# Testing gcc command in Linux From Scratch?

Tags: gcc, cross-compilation, lfs

Linux From Scratch tells me to run these commands to test that the new toolchain is working:

```
echo 'int main(){}' | gcc -xc -
readelf -l a.out | grep ld-linux
```

So since I am testing the new toolchain, `gcc` should run the new GCC (`$LFS_TGT-gcc`) right? If I do `which gcc` it returns `/usr/bin/gcc` for some reason.

Comment: You need to setup the PATH var to include the install bin directory which should precede `/usr/bin/`, or call `gcc` with its full pathname.

Comment: `$PATH` is `/mnt/lfs/tools/bin:/usr/bin`

Comment: If that is correct, then perhaps you need to `rehash` the search path. I would also copy & paste and check that `/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/gcc` actually exists and is executable, and that `PATH` has been re-exported.